# Get UrlHelper instance in MVC 6 without constructor injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In mvc 5 I could do:

```
new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext)
```

I can't use constructor injection because I need the UrlHelper inside an **Attribute** and in Startup.cs as well

Is there a way to resolve the `IUrlHelper` without having an instance of a 
controller or `HtmlHelper`?

Comment: You can get services by calling the GetRequiredService extension method.

Comment: @Pawel extension of what ? I need to call this inside an **Attribute**

Comment: It's an extension method on IServiceProvider - https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/ServiceProviderExtensions.cs

Comment: @Pawel and how do I get an IServiceProvider inside an attribute ? (please read the content of the question)

Comment: @Omu from exactly what kind of attribute are you trying to get it? E.g. a filter? Action selector?

Comment: @Eilon a custom attribute, it doesn't inherit any mvc classes, but it will be used in a `IDisplayMetadaProvider` (similar  to the custom attribute here: http://blog.emikek.com/reinstating-imetadataaware-in-asp-net-5-vnext-mvc-6/); and also I need it in Startup.cs in `ConfigureServices` method

Comment: Try injecting the IHttpContextAccessor into the Attribute constructor and you should be able to derive a UrlHelper from there. var urlHelper = contextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUrlHelper>();